# Python list as *args?

Tags: python, function-composition

I have two Python functions, both of which take variable arguments in their function definitions. To give a simple example:

```
def func1(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print arg

def func2(*args):
    return [2 * arg for arg in args]
```

I'd like to compose them -- as in `func1(func2(3, 4, 5))` -- but I don't want `args` in `func1` to be `([6, 7, 8],)`, I want it to be `(6, 7, 8)`, as if it was called as `func1(6, 7, 8)` rather than `func1([6, 7, 8])`.

Normally, I would just use `func1(*func2(3, 4, 5))` or have `func1` check to see if `args[0]` was a list. Unfortunately, I can't use the first solution in this particular instance and to apply the second would require doing such a check in many places (there are a lot of functions in the role of `func1`).

Does anybody have an idea how to do this? I imagine some sort of introspection could be used, but I could be wrong.

Comment: "`I can't use the first solution in this particular instance`"
Why not?

Comment: I'm using a parser that calls Python functions but doesn't support unpacking in the grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Decorator as posted by Yaroslav.

Minimal example:

```
def unpack_args(func):
    def deco_func(*args):
        if isinstance(args, tuple):
            args = args[0]

        return func(*args)

    return deco_func


def func1(*args):
    return args

def func2(*args):
    return args

@unpack_args
def func3(*args):
    return args

print func1(1,2,3)    # > (1,2,3)
print func2(1,2,3)    # > (1,2,3)
print func1(*func2(1,2,3))    # > (1,2,3)
print func1(func2(1,2,3))    # > ( (1,2,3), )
print func3(func2(1,2,3))   # > (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can consider writing function decorator that checks if the first argument is a list. Applying decorator to existing functions is a bit simpler than modifying functions.

Answer (score 1):

> Normally, I would just use `func1(*func2(3, 4, 5))` or have func1 check to see if `args[0]` was a `list`. Unfortunately, I can't use the first solution in this particular instance and to apply the second would require doing such a check in many places (there are a lot of functions in the role of `func1`).

Why can't you use the first solution?

```
>>> def func1(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print arg

>>> def func2(*args):
    return [2 * arg for arg in args]

>>> func2(3, 4, 5)
[6, 8, 10]
>>> func1(1,2,3)
1
2
3
>>> func1(*func2(3, 4, 5))
6
8
10
>>>
```

If that wasn't possible, you could still have used `func1(*tuple(func2(3, 4, 5)))` (but you don't need to).

Comment: I think that OP has functions returning scalar values, not only tuples or lists. Converting them all to the common standard is too expensive.